# Adding Targets to Target Lists using REST API with SugarCRM

Tags: web-services, rest, sugarcrm

I'm trying to add targets to target lists in Sugar via REST service calls. I'm getting a positive response from Sugar but records are not added. The service method I'm using is *set_relationship*:

```
   {
      "session":"3ece4lmn5rtweq9vm5581jht",
      "module_name":"ProspectLists",
      "module_id":"cb13b96f-8334-733c-1548-52c27a5b8b99",
      "link_field_name":"prospects",
      "name_value_list":[],
      "related_ids":["534f894a-4265-143d-c94b-52be908685b1"],
      "delete":0
   }
```

I also tried it the other way around:

```
   {
      "session":"3ece4lmn5rtweq9vm5581jht",
      "module_name":"Prospects",
      "module_id":"cb13b96f-8334-733c-1548-52c27a5b8b99",
      "link_field_name":"prospect_lists",
      "name_value_list":[],
      "related_ids":["534f894a-4265-143d-c94b-52be908685b1"],
      "delete":0
   }
```

In both cases I get a promising **response**:

```
   {"created":1,"failed":0,"deleted":0}
```

...but when I check the target list I can't find any added targets. I also checked the database but there is no trace either.

My Sugar Version is **6.5.16 CE** and I'm using the SuiteCRM 7.0.1 extension but I don't think this makes a difference here.

Any hint is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It seems like set_relationship is very picky about the parameter order. The parameter naming doesn't even mean a thing. This worked in the end for me:

```
  {
      "session":"3ece4lmn5rtweq9vm5581jht",
      "module_name":"Prospects",
      "module_id":"cb13b96f-8334-733c-1548-52c27a5b8b99",
      "link_field_name":"prospect_lists",
      "related_ids":["534f894a-4265-143d-c94b-52be908685b1"],
      "delete":0
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Python code (API v4.1):

```
import sugarcrm
import json
import requests

crm_session = sugarcrm.Session(CRM_HOST, CRM_USER, CRM_PASS)
payload = {
    "method": "set_relationship",
    "input_type": "JSON",
    "response_type": "JSON",
    "rest_data": json.dumps({
        "session": crm_session.session_id,
        "module_name": "Prospects",
        # ID of the record you're creating relationship FROM
        # In my case it is a record from module "Prospects"
        "module_id": "cb13b96f-8334-733c-1548-52c27a5b8b99",
        "link_field_name": "events_prospects",
        # ID of the record you're creating relationship FOR 
        # In my case it is a record from module "events"
        "related_ids": ["534f894a-4265-143d-c94b-52be908685b1"],
        "name_value_list": [],
        "delete": 0
    })
}
result = requests.post(CRM_HOST, data=payload)
```

@Till is right, be careful with the order of "rest_data" parameters. In my case placing `name_value_list` before `related_ids` has been producing positive results with no actual relationship created.

p.s. I'm using this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sugarcrm/0.1